# function for catching errors by parameters we give it as argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to create authentication function named "access" for my restful API and i want it to look like below for each time user wants be in interaction with server :

```
access(id , token ,function(err){
   if(err){
            res.send(err)
          }else {
            res.send('you have all permissions')
          }
})
```

how can i write this function to use in each authentication step?

Comment: mb it's better to user express middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For authentication you would typically have some middleware:

```js
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  // determine here if user is authenticated (and/or authorized)
  if (user) {
    next(); // user is authorized, call next
  } else {
    const error = new Error('unauthorized');
    error.status = 400;
    return next(err);
  }
}

app.get('/authenticated/route', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  res.send('secret information');
});
```

I would recommend using something like [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/). It removes a lot of the authentication middleware, and especially makes it easy to integrate with providers like Google and Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use is as middleware, if this is for all your entries

```
function access(req, res, next) {
  // verify token
  if (isNotVerified) { return next('You are not verified') }

  // otherwise do what you want to do
  return next()
}
```

and add it to all your routes where you want the user to be verified, someting like this:

```
route.get('/api/private/reports', access, function (req, res) {
  // do some stuff only when user is verified
})

route.get('/api/sensitive/information', access, function (req, res) {
  // do some stuff only when user is verified
})
```

Hope it will help you!